# unmet dependencies problem installing adobe flashplugin

Tags: apt, dependencies, flash

I was trying to install adobe flashplugin in my pc.But while installing it wasn't installed perfectly.I give a screenshot of the terminal while installing.Please help me by recognizing problem and solve it

[image]

```
deb archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner 
deb-src archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner 
deb archive.canonical.com trusty partner 
deb-src archive.canonical.com trusty partner 
deb archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner 
# deb-src archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: 14.04 LTS (32 bit)

Comment: It looks like you are installing the package from another release. How did you add the Partner repo?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `grep partner /etc/apt/sources.list` terminal command. PLEASE ADD IT IS TEXT, NOT A SCREENSHOT!!!

Comment: Here it is,
## 'partner' repository.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ trusty partner
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner

Comment: PLEASE [edit] your question and add the output THERE!!! It is clear that `yakkety` is wrong for 14.04. But it is unreadable in the comments.

Comment: but I do not have enough reputation to post more than 2 link in question

Comment: Do not post links. Post the text.

Comment: OK. See the answer. I will do the edit for you.

Answer (score 2):

You added a wrong repository for your Ubuntu release.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then remove these lines

```
deb archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner 
# deb-src archive.canonical.com/ubuntu yakkety partner
```

Save the file and run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The plugin should install by

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

The lines

```
deb archive.canonical.com trusty partner 
deb-src archive.canonical.com trusty partner
```

are also wrong and should be removed too.